# SQL Server Query filter with order is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-performance

I have been struggling with this for a while.

I have a database with three tables (each of which has millions of records) as follows (removed some columns for simplicity):

```
1.[Entity]
    [Id]                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PK,
    [EntityLevel_Id]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL FK [EntityLevel] ([Id])
2.[EntityData]
    [Id]                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PK,
    [Entity_Id]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL FK [Entity] ([Id]),
    [DataLanguage_Id]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL FK [Language] ([Id]),
    [Code]              NVARCHAR (250) NOT NULL
3.[EntityLevel]
    [Id]                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PK,
    [Sort]              INT NOT NULL
```

There exists indexes As follows

```
[IX_Entity_EntityLevelId] ON [Entity] ([EntityLevel_Id])
[IX_EntityData_EntityId] ON [EntityData] ([Entity_Id])
[IX_EntityData_DataLanguageId_Code] ON [EntityData] ([DataLanguage_Id], [Code])
[IX_EntityLevel_Sort] ON [EntityLevel] ([Sort])
```

To eliminate the possibility that the slowness is because of the selected columns, I only select a fixed value

The following query runs very fast (less than 1 second):

```
SELECT TOP 20
    1
FROM
    [Entity]
    INNER JOIN [EntityData] ON [Entity].[Id] = [EntityData].[Entity_Id]
    INNER JOIN [EntityLevel] ON [Entity].[EntityLevel_Id] = [EntityLevel].[Id]
WHERE
    [EntityData].[DataLanguage_Id] = 'B6930015-F177-4ED3-97B0-AAEF401F9265'
```

The following query also runs very fast:

```
SELECT TOP 20
    1
FROM
    [Entity]
    INNER JOIN [EntityData] ON [Entity].[Id] = [EntityData].[Entity_Id]
    INNER JOIN [EntityLevel] ON [Entity].[EntityLevel_Id] = [EntityLevel].[Id]
WHERE
    [EntityData].[DataLanguage_Id] = 'B6930015-F177-4ED3-97B0-AAEF401F9265'
ORDER BY
    [EntityData].[Code] ASC
```

And the following as well runs fast:

```
SELECT TOP 20
    1
FROM
    [Entity]
    INNER JOIN [EntityData] ON [Entity].[Id] = [EntityData].[Entity_Id]
    INNER JOIN [EntityLevel] ON [Entity].[EntityLevel_Id] = [EntityLevel].[Id]
WHERE
    [EntityLevel].[Sort] = 1
```

BUT, the following query runs VERY SLOW (roughly 10 seconds):

```
SELECT TOP 20
    1
FROM
    [Entity]
    INNER JOIN [EntityData] ON [Entity].[Id] = [EntityData].[Entity_Id]
    INNER JOIN [EntityLevel] ON [Entity].[EntityLevel_Id] = [EntityLevel].[Id]
WHERE
    [EntityData].[DataLanguage_Id] = 'B6930015-F177-4ED3-97B0-AAEF401F9265'
    AND
    [EntityLevel].[Sort] = 1
ORDER BY
    [EntityData].[Code]
```

I don't know the reason, and I don't find any way to apply any more indexes so the query runs faster

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**
the following queries also runs fast:

```
SELECT TOP 20
    1
FROM
    [Entity]
    INNER JOIN [EntityData] ON [Entity].[Id] = [EntityData].[Entity_Id]
    INNER JOIN [EntityLevel] ON [Entity].[EntityLevel_Id] = [EntityLevel].[Id]
WHERE
    [EntityData].[DataLanguage_Id] = 'B6930015-F177-4ED3-97B0-AAEF401F9265'
    AND
    [EntityLevel].[Sort] = 1
```

And

```
SELECT TOP 20
    1
FROM
    [Entity]
    INNER JOIN [EntityData] ON [Entity].[Id] = [EntityData].[Entity_Id]
    INNER JOIN [EntityLevel] ON [Entity].[EntityLevel_Id] = [EntityLevel].[Id]
WHERE
    [EntityLevel].[Sort] = 1
ORDER BY
    [EntityData].[Code]
```

The problem appears only with order by and the two filters

Comment: is `sort=1` a common filter? a filtered index will be helpful for this. Just a note that you are working with an EAV database here which are well known for performance and scalability issues

Comment: sort=1 is not a common filter, it's common to filter by sort but the value is not common, what I lack to understand is that it's just normal join and the query runs very fast with several conditons but slows down with the order by and the two filters

Comment: It's using a different query plan. When you observe them and try and work out why it's doing it you can often fix it. Quite often just updating stats sorts it out. Sometimes the issue is parameter sniffing

Comment: OK just rereading, it's narrowed down to the `order by code`? Code is not the leading column in any index so I guess the order by (always an expensive operation) is the issue. A clustered index usually fixes order by performance issues but you only get one.

Comment: Again I have to comment on the EAV design _and_ the guid pk's. This is seems like a fantastic idea to a developer but to a DBA it's not.

Comment: I did update the statistics and the result is the same, will edit the question and include the actual execution plan

Comment: I understand the EAV problem, however this specific query is just usual join, just the same if the table [EntityData] is something else (like [Person]), and I can try to add an index on code alone and see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is concerned, this is the solution to the problem:

It turned out that with that much rows, what was taking time is to make key lookups and hash matches due to different indexes, so the solution was to add the following index to allow using of a single index on the table for all filter (and order by) values:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EntityData_EntityId_DataLanguageId_IncCode] ON [EntityData] ([Entity_Id], [DataLanguage_Id]) INCLUDE ([Code])
```

But since I may also filter by code in some situations and not only use order by, so I modified the index to be like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EntityData_EntityId_DataLanguageId_Code] ON [EntityData] ([Entity_Id], [DataLanguage_Id], [Code])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try indexes on

1. `[Entity] ([Id], [EntityLevel_Id])`,
2. `[EntityData] ([DataLanguage_Id], [Entity_id], [Code])` and
3. `[EntityLevel] ([Sort], [Id])`.

Experiment with the order of columns. For 2. and 3. I assumed that `[EntityData].[DataLanguage_Id] = 'B6930015-F177-4ED3-97B0-AAEF401F9265'` and `[EntityLevel].[Sort] = 1` in the `WHERE` clause filter more than the join does. But I don't know the data and that assumption might be wrong.

Comment: I might be getting something wrong, but can you please explain why I need index #1 as it should be already exists because [Id] is PK and clustered index?, also index #3, why would I need to include the PK column in an index? isn't it already included in all indexes?, for the assumption, the query runs fast without the order by

Comment: @AhmedMSedeek: I couldn't (and still cannot) find that information in your post. But anyway, I don't know if you *need* it, you have to test that for yourself. I cannot do that because I don't have the data and everything. It think it possibly might help the join better than the clustered index though, as it also sorts by `[EntityLevel_Id]`. And then there's the possibility, when changing the order, as i mentioned, that `([EntityLevel_Id], [Id])` is the better option. The clustered index doesn't cover that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about this query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 1
FROM [Entity] JOIN
     [EntityData]
     ON [Entity].[Id] = [EntityData].[Entity_Id] JOIN
     [EntityLevel]
     ON [Entity].[EntityLevel_Id] = [EntityLevel].[Id]
WHERE [EntityData].[DataLanguage_Id] = 'B6930015-F177-4ED3-97B0-AAEF401F9265' AND
      [EntityLevel].[Sort] = 1
ORDER BY [EntityData].[Code];
```

I think the issue is that SQL Server cannot use the index for sorting.  You may be able to get around this using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT TOP 20 1
FROM Entity e JOIN
     EntityData ed
     ON e.Id = ed.Entity_Id 
WHERE ed.DataLanguage_Id = 'B6930015-F177-4ED3-97B0-AAEF401F9265' AND          
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM EntityLevel el
              WHERE e.EntityLevel_Id = el.Id AND
                    el.Sort = 1
             )
ORDER BY ed.Code;
```

For this version, you want an index on `EntityLevel(ID, Sort)`.

This *may* allow the SQL engine to use the index for sorting (as it seems to do in other cases).  Of course, you cannot select any columns from `EntityLevel` -- but your example queries don't do this anyway.